# ASP.Net SQLExpress: Cannot open user default database. Login failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express

I have 2 SQL express databases:  one for my application data and another for the MembershipProvider data.  When I attempt to use the CreateUserWizard control, I get the following error:

> Error:    Login failed for user 'SFP\Susan'.

I can connect to thesee the DB in the server explorer and all its tables and data.  What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the MembershipProvider connection is not correctly set up in your `web.config` file. It should look something like this (with "MyAwesomeDatabaseConnectionName" being the name of the configured connection string, in the `connectionStrings` section of the file):

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="MyAwesomeDatabaseConnectionName" 
         applicationName="MyAwesomeApp"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Also, it looks like you are configured for Windows authentication, but if your membership data is in a database, you'll want to configure for Forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/myloginpage.aspx" 
         defaultUrl="~/myhomepage.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: In the provider block, can the NAME be anything or is it the name of my database, ASPNETDB.

Comment: It can be anything. Your database connection string is referenced in the 'connectionStringName' property.